# Running bundle install with modifier on certain gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to work on a project that uses the mysql2 gem, version 0.3.17 specifically.

I can get this to install by running:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql\connector -v '0.3.17'
```

However after doing this (in the projects directory), and then run bundle install, it fails with the message

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.17), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Is there any way to run something like

```
bundle install -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql\connector -v '0.3.17'
```

? I'm guessing I would need to specifiy the mysql2 gem in the command but I've looked on http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html and can't seem to find anything.

My other option would be to simply point it to the gem I've already installed if that's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this can help you: http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: Thank you so much put that as an answer so I can accept it!